# How convert epoch time integerfield to datetime field in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I use django and for saving time I am using `epoch time` in an `IntegerField` so my model is like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    start_time = models.IntegerField()
```

and start_time in admin is like this:

[image: start_time integerfield]

It's not a problem but it's hard to check and update field for a person so my question is how can I convert this `IntegerField` to `DateTimeField` in django admin without changing my model? I know I can represent this field as readonly field and convert epoch time to DateTime but how can i use django admin DateTime picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I found my answer hope it help someone else, it's work but maybe it's not the best answer.**

I used an intermediate field because I couldn't change the real field so I create a form to have a DateTimeField:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminSplitDateTime


class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_date_time = forms.SplitDateTimeField(widget=AdminSplitDateTime())

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

then I add form to my admin:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
    fields = ('start_date_time',)
```

for setting initial value of previous saved object in form:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    if obj:
        form.base_fields['start_date_time'].initial = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(obj.start_time)
    return form
```

the result is:

[image: epoch datetime field]

and last step is saving DateTimeField to IntegerField as epoch time:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.start_time = round(form.cleaned_data['start_date_time'].timestamp())
    obj.save()
```